# Saripaar's @ConfirmPassword not working

Tags: android, validation, user-interface, saripaar

I have the following fragment using Saaripar's annotations to validate some fields:

```
/**
 * Simple fragment used to register a new user
 */
public static class FragmentRegister extends Fragment implements Validator.ValidationListener {

    @InjectView(R.id.display_name_label)
    TextView displayNameLabel;

    @NotEmpty(messageResId = R.string.validation_not_empty)
    @InjectView(R.id.display_name)
    EditText displayName;

    @InjectView(R.id.username_label)
    TextView nameLabel;

    @NotEmpty(messageResId = R.string.validation_not_empty)
    @InjectView(R.id.username)
    EditText username;

    @InjectView(R.id.password_label)
    TextView passwordLabel;

    @InjectView(R.id.password)
    @Password
    @Size(min = 6, messageResId = R.string.validation_6_characters)
    EditText password;

    @InjectView(R.id.confirm_password_label)
    TextView confirmPasswordLabel;

    @InjectView(R.id.confirm_password)
    @ConfirmPassword
    EditText confirmPassword;

    @InjectView(R.id.create_user_button)
    Button createUserButton;

    private Validator validator;

    public FragmentRegister() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);

        // Set up Saripaar validator
        validator = new Validator(this);
        validator.setValidationListener(this);

        // Injecting views with ButterKnife
        ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);

        return rootView;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        ButterKnife.reset(this);
    }

    // Injected view listeners
    @OnClick(R.id.create_user_button)
    public void createUser() {
        validator.validate();
    }

    // Saripaar callbacks

    @Override
    public void onValidationSucceeded() {
        clearErrors();
        String dispName = displayName.getText().toString();
        String user = username.getText().toString();
        String pass = password.getText().toString();

        Controller.instance().register(user, dispName, pass);
        getActivity().finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onValidationFailed(List<ValidationError> errors) {
        clearErrors();
        View view = null;
        for (ValidationError error : errors) {
            view = error.getView();
            if (view instanceof EditText) {
                ((EditText) view).setError(error.getFailedRules().get(0).getMessage(getActivity()));
            }
        }
        if(view != null) {
            view.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    public void clearErrors() {
        displayName.setError(null);
        username.setError(null);
        password.setError(null);
        confirmPassword.setError(null);
    }
}
```

`@ConfirmPassword` never works, it just shows an empty error message for the `@Password` field and "The passwords do not match" for `@ConfirmPassword`. Any idea of what could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/issues/52 Seems its a bug and it will be fixed today.

Comment: It has been fixed, check the latest snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a message to the confirm password feild like

```
@InjectView(R.id.confirm_password)
@ConfirmPassword(order = 6, message = "Password mismatch")
EditText confirmPassword;
```

Comment: @George Thomas, I believe this is regarding the 2.0-SNAPSHOT version of Saripaar. You are using v1 of the same library.

Comment: i also thought wats wrong! its working fine for me. :)
may be he will fix it soon